# Prevent iframe from loading responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

My app has a functionality that loads another route in a `iframe`. The intention is to change some layout settings, colors etc and see how that page will look in the browser in its final and original version (100% in a desktop or laptop).

The problem is that the iframe is loaded in a div that has something like 2/3 of the system's width (it's a Bootstrap column). This is smaller than our media-query breakpoint and the iframe content is loading the responsive design. But that breaks the rule in paragraph one.

I needed it to be a miniaturized version of the original page.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

What I am trying to do is somehow similar to this on Google's PageSpeed:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F&tab=desktop

THe difference is that Google takes a picture and in my app the user must be allowed to interact with the page, browse other links, click buttons etc. It is a screen simulator/previewer but not responsive.

Comment: Of course you're getting this effect - media queries are based on the viewport with, and the iframe establishes its own. Workaround: Make the iframe element larger, and then scale it down again using CSS.

Comment: scale it down with `transform` ?

Answer (score 3):

As CBroe mentioned, the problem is that the CSS for the page loaded within the iframe is using the size of the iframe as it's viewport size. You'll want to size the iframe according to how you want the actual page to display (1200px wide, for example) then use a `scale` transform to reduce the size of the iframe.

Your HTML could look like:

```
<iframe width="1200" height="600" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

Then rescale using CSS:

```
iframe {
  transform: scale(0.3);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Here's a live example: https://codepen.io/JoshuaToenyes/pen/gMMLze

Comment: Genius! Thank youuu! I'm using it inside a bootstrap column with `transform: scale(0.5);width:200%` so that I don't need a static width.